# How to get the CheckBoxlist value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkboxlist

Using below javascript function can able to get the all the text of checkbox list. But can't able to get the value (It passing as "on").

```
var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=chkFun.ClientID%>");
var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
var label = CHK.getElementsByTagName("label");
var listOfSpans = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    var value = checkbox[i].value;
    alert("Selected = " + label[i].innerHTML);  //Get the text          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a checkbox is "on" which is what you are getting. You are not setting the value of the checkbox properly.

> If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on , so the submitted data in that case would be [name]=on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox